# Detect pending system shutdown with cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4, osx-snow-leopard, shutdown

How do I detect when a computer is about to shut down with cocoa?  There doesn't seem to be anything out there on the internet.  This has to differentiate between shutdown and logout.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

Same code as Matthias provided, but change the name of the notification into:

**NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification**

And if you want to prevent system's shutdown, please add

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    return NSTerminateCancel;
}
```

be sure of using "NSApplicationDelegate"

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

The following code from the official documentation may help you:

```
 - (void) receiveSleepNote: (NSNotification*) note
 {
     NSLog(@"receiveSleepNote: %@", [note name]);
 }

 - (void) receiveWakeNote: (NSNotification*) note
 {
     NSLog(@"receiveSleepNote: %@", [note name]);
 }

 - (void) fileNotifications
 {
     //These notifications are filed on NSWorkspace's notification center, not the default 
     // notification center. You will not receive sleep/wake notifications if you file 
     //with the default notification center.
     [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver: self 
        selector: @selector(receiveSleepNote:) 
        name: NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification object: NULL];

     [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver: self 
        selector: @selector(receiveWakeNote:) 
        name: NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification object: NULL];
 }
```

For more information see: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1340/_index.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Was not what I wanted however.  Does not tell me how to detect shutdown.  I will search developer.